# How to present a character Unicode with 5 digit (Hex) with c# language

Tags: c#

I want to print a Unicode character with 5 hexadecimal digits on the screen (for example to write it on a Windows Forms button).

For example, the Unicode of the character Ace Heart is 1F0B1.  I tried it with `\x` but it can present up to 4 digits.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `\U` escape sequence:

```
string text = "Ace of hearts: \U0001f0b1";
```

Of course, you'll have to be using a font which supports that character...

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend *avoiding* the `\x` escape sequence, as they're hard to read. For example:

```
string good = "Bell: \x7Good compiler";
string bad = "Bell: \x7Bad compiler";
```

When presented together, at first glance it would seem that these are both "Bell: " followed by U+0007 followed by either "Good compiler" or "Bad" compiler... but because "Bad" is entirely composed of valid hex characters, the second string is actually "Bell: " followed by U+7BAD followed by " compiler".